# Nonlinear function continuous but not bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like an example of a map $f:H\rightarrow R$, where $H$ is a (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space, and $R$ is the real numbers, such that $f$ is continuous, but $f$ is not bounded on the close unit ball $\{ x\in H : \|x\| \leq 1\}$.

Actually, $H$ could be replaced by any Banach space (but not just a normed space-- that's too easy).  My motivation is that if $f$ is linear, this is impossible; but I have next to no intuition about non-linear functions.

**Edit:** Here's an example for $c_0$ which is even differentiable (disclaimer: I found it here: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~larry/paper.dir/korea.ps).  Define $f:c_0\rightarrow F$ (where F is your field, real or complex) by $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^n \qquad (x=(x_n)). $$  You can estimate the sum by a geometric progression, so it does converge.  A bit of checking shows that f is Frechet differentible (so certainly continuous).  But $f(1,1,\cdots,1,0,\cdots)=n$ (if there are $n$ ones) so $f$ is not bounded on the closed unit ball.  What I don't immediately see is how to adapt this to $\ell^2$, say.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An easy way of doing it in any infinite-dimensional Banach space is to observe that there is a countable discrete subset $\{x_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of the unit ball by [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) (in the Hilbert case you can simply take any orthonormal system). This means that you can find a sequence or radii $r_{n}$ such that the closed balls $\bar{B}_{2r_{n}}(x_{n})$ are pairwise disjoint (take e.g. $r_{n} = \frac{1}{4}$ in the Hilbert setting - I'm being generous here). Putting $f_{n}(x) = \max{\{0,r_{n} - \|x- x_n\|\}}$ you get a continuous function $f_n$ supported on $\bar{B}_{r_n}(x_n)$. The function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{r_n} f_n(x)$ is unbounded on the unit ball because $f(x_{n}) = n$ and it is clearly continuous since the balls $\bar{B}_{2r_n}(x_n)$ are pairwise disjoint.

I don't know of a "natural" example off the top of my head.

Comment: Ah, nice!  Actually, in the meantime, I found a differentiable example.  I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 5):

Can't one reason in the following manner?

Let $H=\ell^2$ and let $\{ e^n:=(\delta_m^n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be its standard base ($\delta_m^n$ is Kronecker).

Then consider the open balls $B_n:=B(e^n;\frac{1}{2})$: these balls are pairwise disjoint (because the sum of their radii is less than the distance between their centers, which equals $\sqrt{2}$).

In each ball set $f(x):=(n^2+1)(1-2|x-e^n|)$, so that $f(x)$ is radially-decreasing, continuous and bounded in $B_n$ (for the image of $B_n$ is the interval $]0,n^2+1]$) and $f(x)$ approaches zero when $x$ approaches the boundary $\partial B_n$.

Now we have a function $f(x)$ defined on $\bigcup_n B_n$ and we want to extend it to the whole space: the easier way to do this is by setting $f(x)=0$ when $x\notin \bigcup_n B_n$.

The extended function $f(x)$ is defined, continuous and unbounded in $\ell^2$ (for it is unbounded on $B(o;1)$, because $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}|f(e^n)|= +\infty$), and it is obviously nonlinear: in fact if $R>0$ is sufficiently large, then $f(Re^0+Re^1)=0\neq 3R=Rf(e^0)+Rf(e^1)$ .

It makes sense for me. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry Theo; I totally forgot a factor $n^2$ in the definition of $f(x)$ in $B_n$.

Comment: No problem. Now the example is perfectly fine. I removed my comment as it is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The example that you gave for $c_0$ can be slightly modified to give a map that works for the $\ell^p$  also.

$$(a_n) \mapsto \sum_n n a_n^n$$
is continuous on $c_0$ with the $\sup $  norm so also on all the $l_p$ with their norm. But $e_n \mapsto n$ so the map is not bounded on the unit ball.

If the Banach space has a Schauder base $e_n$, $(\|e_n \| = 1$), then we have a similar map
$$\sum_n a_n e_n \mapsto \sum_n n a_n^n$$

It would be interesting to provide "direct" examples for other concrete Banach spaces, like  $C([0,1])$, or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, without using bases.

$\bf{Added:}$ Example for $C([0,1])$. Consider a continuous linear functional of norm $1$ which does not achieve its maximum on the unit ball, for example $l(f) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f(t) d t - \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(t) dt$, and take $\phi(f) = \frac{1}{1- l(f)}$ on the closed unit ball.

For $c_0$, take $l(a_n) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{a_n}{2^n}$, of norm $1$, but maximum $1$ not achieved on the closed unit ball.

For $\ell^1$, take $l(a_n) = \sum (1-\frac{1}{n}) a_n$, norm $1$, $\ldots$.

Such examples are possible  only for spaces that are not [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Characterizations_of_reflexive_spaces).

$\bf{Added:}$

For $L^p([0,1])$ ($p\ge 1$) consider the continuous functional ( non-linear) on the closed unit ball
$$f\mapsto T(f)\colon = \int_0^1 t |f(t)|^p d t$$
with supremum $1$, but which is not achieved. Then $f\mapsto \frac{1}{1-T(f)}$ is continuous and unbounded on the closed unit ball.

$\bf{Added:}$ @iolo: was kind to point out that the last examples are only defined on the unit ball ( but note that they are unbounded on the unit sphere). To fix this, compose the maps with $x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ outside the unit ball. @iolo also points out that the first one is  *convex* -- so,  a convex, continuous map on the full space, not bounded on the unit ball.

Comment: Your first example is particularly nice because it is a continuous and also convex function that is unbounded on the unit ball!

Comment: @iolo: Oh, thanks!  Now that you pointed out the convexity, I wonder if the others are not  convex, since $t\mapsto 1/(1-t)$ is convex and increasing?

Comment: Well, I was myself looking for such an example, so I was happy to find one. Yes, that example should also be convex, but you defined it on the unit ball only and not on the whole space. So to me the first example was nicer.

Comment: @iolo: Great, thanks, I added this info to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another construct.  Let $H$ be any Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis.  Then $\|e_n - e_m\|^2 = 2$ if $m\not = n$, so
$\|e_m - e_n\| = \sqrt{2}$ if $m \not= n$.

Denote by $U_n$ the closed unit ball about $e_n$.  Each $U_n$ is closed and is a positive uniform distance ($\sqrt{2} - 1$) from any other $ U_n$; the union of these balls is closed.  Put $U = \bigcup_n U_n$.  Now define the function $f: U \rightarrow R$ by $f(n) = n$ if $x \in U_n$.

Since $U$ is a closed subset of the ball of radius 2 about the origin in $H$, by the Tietze extension theorem, there is a continuous extension of  $f$ defined on the closed ball of radius 2 about the origin.  This function is continuous and unbounded.

Comment: How is that different? You're replacing an easy explicit construction by appealing to a somewhat subtle theorem, but the idea is exactly the same.