# A continuous mapping with the unbounded image of the unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space, and let $B=\{x\in X: \|x\|\leq 1\}$ be the closed unit ball of $X$. Please give an example of a continuous mapping $F: X\to X$ such that $F(B)$ is unbounded.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29498/nonlinear-function-continuous-but-not-bounded) is a related question.

Comment: Required to be linear?!

Comment: I really don't understand why people vote to close *so often* for *ridiculous* reasons: Here as "off-topic" and "unclear what you're asking". I don't have a clean slate either: I voted to close too, but as "duplicate". Someone else gave a link in the comments. I noticed they seem really duplicates, thus voted to close - but only after checking. Moreover if unclear what is asked then *be constructive*!! Ask in a comment or assume the closest as some guys usually do here on MSE. **Folks be more gentle.**

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: The following works on any non-reflexive infinite-dimensional Banach space.

Suppose $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $X$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ but $f(x) < 1$ for all $x \in B$, i.e. $f$ does not assume its supremum on $B$.  Take $F(x) = x/(1-f(x))$ for $x \in B$, and $F(x) = F(x/\|x\|)$ on its complement.

For example, on the space $c_0$ of sequences converging to $0$ you could take $f(x) = \sum_j f_j x_j$ where $\sum_j |f_j| = 1$ and all $f_j \ne 0$.

EDIT: For a surjective version, let $$F(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-f(x/\max(1,\|x\|)}$$

EDIT: Here's a construction that works in any infinite-dimensional Banach space. There is a sequence $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\| = 1$ and $\|x_i - x_j\| > 1/2$ for $i \ne j$. 
Thus the closed balls $B_{1/4}(x_n) = \{x: \|x - x_n\| \le 1/4\}$ are disjoint.  Define 
$$ F(x) = \cases{ (1 - 4 \|x - x_n\|) (n-1) x_n + x &   if $x \in B_{1/4}(x_n)$\cr
x & if $x$ is not in any $B_{1/4}(x_n)$\cr}$$
Note that $F(x_n) = n x_n$ (which makes $F$ unbounded on $B$), while $F(x) = x$ on the boundary of $B_{1/4}(x_n)$.

Comment: Can this map be made to be surjective?

Comment: You must be assuming $f$ is continuous. Did you mean to assume as well that $X$ is not reflexive?

Comment: Yes, this requires $X$ to be non-reflexive.

Comment: Hmm. Feel like I'm risking court-martial... maybe you didn't notice that the hypotheses about non-reflexivity of $X$ and continuity of $f$ are missing from the current version of your answer?

Comment: @RobertIsrael where do I get such a $f$ in general?

Comment: Great, thanks!${}$

Comment: @user251257 I'm pretty sure it's easy to see there is no such $f$ if $X$ is reflexive. It's clear that there is no such $f$ in general, for example it's clear that there is no such $f$ if $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: James's theorem says $X$ is reflexive iff every  continuous linear functional on $X$ attains its maximum on $B$.

Comment: nice, thx @DavidC.Ullrich and .@RobertIsrael