# Existence of a continuous mapping that maps the closed unit ball onto its exterior

Tags: functional-analysis

I saw the post about a continuous mapping $F: X \to X$ where $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space that maps the closed unit ball of $X$ onto the unbounded set.

[A continuous mapping with the unbounded image of the unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354180/a-continuous-mapping-with-the-unbounded-image-of-the-unit-ball-in-an-infinite-di)

It is very interesting to me, is there such a continuous mapping $F: X \to X$ that maps the closed unit ball of $X$ onto its exterior.

That is, let, as in the previous link, $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space, $B=\{x\in X: \|x\| \leq 1\}$, $E=\{x\in X: \|x\| \geq 1\}$.

Does there exist a continuous mapping $F: X \to X$ such that $F(B)=E$? Or, at least, $F(B)\subset E$.

Comment: You could simply translate $B$ to have $F(B) \subset E.$

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem.** If $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space then $B\subset X$ is homeomorphic to $E\subset X$.

**Proof.** First of all, $B$ is homeomorphic to $X$ (Theorem 6.2 in the book "Selected Topics in Infinite Dimensional Topology" by  Bessaga and Pelczynski). On the other hand, the inversion 
$$
J: x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|^2}
$$
sends $E$ homeomorphically to $B-\{0\}$. Thus, it remains to show that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X-\{0\}$. This is a special case of Corollary 5.1 in the same book: For every compact subset $K\subset X$, the space $X$ is homeomorphic to $X-K$.   qed