# $\mathcal C^0(X)$ implies locally bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

A quick question to which I need an answer for my research thesis.

Let $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ where $X$ is a Banach space and assume that $f \in \mathcal C^0(X)$. This implies that it is locally bounded (it is bounded on bounded sets) as in finite dimension, right?

Comment: What do you ean by locally bounded ? bounded on compact set ? if yes, then of course it's true...

Comment: Not compact sets. I mean bounded on bounded sets

Comment: Should follow directly from the definition of the $C^0$ space

Comment: Locally bounded: yes. Bounded on bounded sets: no! See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354180/a-continuous-mapping-with-the-unbounded-image-of-the-unit-ball-in-an-infinite-di

Comment: If $f$ is not linear, then this is likely not true. Here is a counterexample if you allow $f\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined only on an open subset $U\subset X$. Let $X$ be the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$ and let $U$ be the subset of functions that do not have a zero. If $f(x)=x^{-1}$, then $U\cap \{\Vert x \Vert_{\infty}\le 1\}$ is *not* mapped to a bounded set. You can probably get something on $U=X$ by modifying this example by suitable cutoff's around the zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true if $X$ is infinite-dimensional. Take a countable number of disjoint balls $B(x_n,\epsilon)$ inside the unit ball of $X$. Define any continuous function $f_n$ on $B(x_n,\epsilon)$ that satisfies $f_n(x_n) = n$ and $f|_{\partial B(x_n,\epsilon)} \equiv 0$. Extend each $f_n$ by $0$ to a continuous function on $X$. Now consider $f = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_n$. Clearly $f$ is continuous as the supports of the summands are disjoint. But $f$ is also unbounded on the unit ball of $X$.